# Q factor in RLC circuit

Tags: voltage, resistors, passive-networks, tank

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor)

> [image]

the definition of the Q factor it is the ratio of energy stored/energy dissipated per cycle*2π

If we have an underdamped oscillation of a RLC circuit does this mean for every cycle(of the many)during the decay it is the energy stored before the cycle started/energy dissipated on that cycle?

Comment: Q is a mathematical definition in the s-domain. It's \$\frac1{2\:\zeta}\$. It's *related* to dissipation in the time domain. But the precise definition is mathematical and s-domain. So you'd need to work out your own answer in the time domain, as it doesn't have a defined meaning there, so far as I'm aware anyway.

Comment: Is this for a a real or ideal circuit?

Comment: @VoltageSpike it is ideal circuit without any noise or any capacitances and inductances of the cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we have an underdamped oscillation of a RLC circuit does this mean for every cycle(of the many)during the decay it is the energy stored before the cycle started/energy dissipated on that cycle?

Short answer: Yes. Let \$E_0\$ be the total energy stored in the system at a certain time and \$E_1\$ the energy one period later. Then

$$
\frac{E_0}{E_1-E_0} = \frac{\text{energy at the start of a period}}{\text{energy dissipated in that one period}}
$$

will be a constant.

Here's a calculation to demonstrate what's going on...

Assume we have an ideal RLC circuit. The energy in the circuit is stored in the reactive elements, the inductor and capacitor. We know that the current \$I(t)\$ through the inductor will have the form:

$$
I(t) = I_o e^{-\gamma t} \cos \omega t
$$

for some constants \$I_0\$ and \$\gamma\$. Here \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency, \$2\pi f\$.

Since this is an ideal circuit, the energy in the system at the times \$t_n = \frac{2\pi n}{\omega}\$ will be contained completely in the inductor, and this energy will be proportional to the current squared. That is,

$$
\begin{align}
E(t_n) &= k I^2(t_n) = k I_0^2 e^{-2\gamma t_n} \cos(\omega t_n) = k I_0^2 e^{-2\gamma t_n} \\
       &= k I_0^2 \beta^n
\end{align}
$$
where \$\beta = \exp( -4\pi\gamma/\omega )\$. Note that the times \$t_0, t_1, t_2, \dots\$ are exactly one period apart.

The energy dissipated between \$t_n\$ and \$t_{n+1}\$ -- i.e. one cycle -- is:

$$
\begin{align}
E(t_{n}) - E(t_{n+1}) &= k I_0^2 \beta^{n} - k I_0^2 \beta^{n+1} \\
                    &= k I_0^2 (1 - \beta) \beta^n \\
\end{align}
$$
and therefore the ratio of the energy at the start of the cycle to the energy dissipated in that cycle is:

$$
  \frac{E(t_n)}{ E(t_n) - E(t_{n+1})} = \frac{ k I_0^2 \beta^n }{ k I_0^2 (1-\beta) \beta^n} = \frac{1}{1-\beta}
$$

And this is a constant independent of time.